# writing O(n+1) as the complexity of an algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

[image]During the last week, I learned the subject of ADT List and its implementations with arrays and linked list.
In the ADT of list we saw few methods. (Attached)
One of them was the Concat method. When we analyzed the complexity of this method in the implementation with arrays , it was said the the complexity of it is O(n2+1) and not O(n2) , since n2 - the length of the second list might be zero and we dont want to say that if the input size is 0 then the run-time of the algorithm is 0.
this issue made me really confused since as I realized when a function, (lets call her f(n)), is O(n), doesn't mean that f(0) = 0 or f = O(o) .
This issue with the +1 in a method with O(n) complexity continued during the lesson , and got me really confused. It is clear to me that every function this is O(n) is also O(n+1) but it is unclear to me the explanation that we define the complexity as O(n+1) since the input size might be 0. Thank you for your help everyone :)

I thought that the explanation might be that as the definition for a function that is O(n) is: there is c and n_0 s.t. for every n > n_0 f(n) <= c*n , we are treating it as it : there is c s.t. for every n>= 0
f(n)<= c*n . And here if we will say that f(n) is O(n) , by this definition , so here is says that in inputsize of 0 the runtime is zero, but if we say f(n) <= c* (n+1) then in 0 the runtime isnt zero. (that's what i understood when i asked my teacher this question)

Comment: what do you mean .. "..... not O(n2) , since n2 - the length of the second list might be zero" ?

Comment: We are expressing the *asymptotic* complexity of functions. The special case *n=0* is not relevant. *O(n)* and *O(n + 1)* are the same complexity class.

Comment: Writing it as *O(n + 1)* is not incorrect, and possibly it could be used for convenience to convey extra information to the reader, e.g. a reminder that running this algorithm on empty input will take some nonzero amount of time. But i find it highly unnecessary and confusing.